# "Flyers" vs. "Passengers of a flight" What's the difference?

Tags: word-usage, difference

"The ___ were served two meals during the flight."
a. flyers  b.clients  c.passengers d.travelers
Correct Answer: **c.passengers**
My question is why isn't option **a. flyers** correct, since a flyer is somebody who travels by plane ? When is it usually used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is quite simple. When we talk about passengers we mean only passengers, not passengers + pilot + engineer + officers +other crew or staff working on the aircraft, which flyers mean. Passengers is the most appropriate word to be used here. Isn't it unnatural to say "The flyers were served two meals during the flight, especially when we have an appropriate word?

I know flyer is a synonym of passenger, but like other synonyms they are not necessarily interchangeable in all cases.  We have another synonym traveller. I think it also does not properly fit in the sentence mentioned. We often read frequent flyers instead of frequent passengers. What I mean is that the use of synonyms depends very much on the situation or condition we are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible** because the word 'flyer' ***does*** mean [a person who travels in a plane as a passenger](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/flyer).

A verdict from the [High Court of India document](http://www.delhicourts.nic.in/MARCH2013/MARCH2013/Oberoi%20Flight%20Services%20Vs.%20Sudesh%20Yadav.pdf) reads -

> The respondent before this Court was engaged in preparation and packaging of ***food for the various airlines, for being served to the flyers.*** One of the airlines for which packed food used to be prepared by the appellant was British Airways.

But since the word *flyer* has other close meanings as well, the option *passengers* serves the purpose without any ambiguity.

[Few of those meanings](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flyer) of a *flyer* include...

> a person who flies an aircraft (usually a small one, not a passenger plane) 
>  
>   a person who operates something such as a model aircraft or a kite from the ground. 
>  a person, an animal or a vehicle that moves very quickly.

*Passengers* is the word that talks about nothing but the people on plane traveling from one place to another and is less ambiguous than the word *flyers*.

Comment: It's not really about ambiguity.  *Flyer* just isn't the right word for the context.  (I don't know of any reason why other than that *passenger* is conventionalized in this context.)

Comment: Your answer contains at least five instances of non-idiomatic English (including an error in subject-verb agreement). It reads almost like broken English. I don't find this helpful. In addition, the issue is not about ambiguity,  but about word usage, as sailboat says.

Comment: @snailboat what do you think about 'frequent flyers' then?

Comment: @carsmack enlighten me further then

Comment: I think *frequent flyer* is a fixed phrase distinct from *flyer* with separate patterns of usage.  All three terms are appropriate in different contexts.

Comment: The option *passengers* **serves** the purpose.

Comment: @CarSmack Thank you. Waiting for rest 4 to improve my language. :)

Comment: @snailboat nope. *flyers* can be used in that context as well. Answer edited, reference added.

Comment: Well, I see only two after your 04 Oct edit. (a) We would say "a few," not "few." (b) the last sentence, *people on a plane." In other words the indefinite article rather than no article.

Answer (score 1):

A flyer (var. flier) is someone who travels by plane *from time to time*.  Fliers are people who (usually) take planes when they travel.

A flier can be standing on *terra firma*.  To be a flier, all that is necessary is that one has taken a plane and remains willing to take a plane and plans to take planes in the future.

A flyer on a particular flight is a *passenger* on the flight.

A nervous flier is someone with a fear of flying. You could ask a person sitting beside you on the train, "Are you a nervous flier?", and they could answer "Yes".  It means they get  nervous *whenever* they fly in a plane.  You don't have to be in a plane to be a nervous flier.  And you don't have to be in a plane to be a flier.